# f string not updating inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I'm trying to create the game Yahtzee in python, but I am having trouble putting the points in a table I made. The table is a list with each item corresponding to one row. Each item (meaning each row) is an f-string which retrieves a value from a dictionary inside curly brackets.

Later in the code, I update the value that is being called on in the row, and print the row. For some reason, the old value from the dictionary is the one that gets printed.

```
from random import randrange

def roll(saved):
    global roll
    roll = []
    for i in range(5 - len(saved)):
        roll.append(str(randrange(1,7)))
    global roll_og
    roll_og = roll
    roll.sort()
    print("Avaliable dice : " + ",".join(roll))

def avaliable_points():
#numbers
    global roll_og
    for i in range(1,7):
        if roll_og.count(str(i)) > 0:
            points[str(i)] = roll_og.count(str(i)) * i


def print_table(table):
    for i in table:
        print(i)


saved = []

points = {
    "1" : "",
    "2" : "",
    "3" : "",
    "4" : "",
    "5" : "",
    "6" : ""
}

avaliable_grid = [
     " _____________________________          _____________________________",
     "|           |Player 1|Player 2|        |           |Player 1|Player 2|",
     "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    f"|Ones       |{points[str(1)]}|        |        |3 of a Kind|        |        |",
    f"|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    f"|Twos       |{points[str(2)]}|        |        |4 of a Kind|        |        |",
    f"|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    f"|Threes     |{points[str(3)]}|        |        |Full House |        |        |",
    f"|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    f"|Fours      |{points[str(4)]}|        |        |S. Straight|        |        |",
    f"|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    f"|Fives      |{points[str(5)]}|        |        |L. Straight|        |        |",
    f"|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    f"|Sixes      |{points[str(6)]}|        |        |Chance     |        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    "|#############################|        |YAHTZEE    |        |        |",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    f"|Sum        |        |        |        |#############################|",
    "|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|",
    f"|Bonus      |        |        |        |TOTAL SCORE|        |        |",
    " -----------------------------          ----------------------------- ",
    ]


roll(saved)
avaliable_points()
print(points)
print_table(avaliable_grid)
```

The table I care about is the `available_grid` list, and the dictionary is the `points` dictionary. All the other functions in the code are the ones that determine how many points go into each slot in the table.

```
Avaliable dice : 1,2,2,4,6
{'1': 1, '2': 4, '3': '', '4': 4, '5': '', '6': 6}
 _____________________________          _____________________________
|           |Player 1|Player 2|        |           |Player 1|Player 2|
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Ones       ||        |        |3 of a Kind|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Twos       ||        |        |4 of a Kind|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Threes     ||        |        |Full House |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Fours      ||        |        |S. Straight|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Fives      ||        |        |L. Straight|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Sixes      ||        |        |Chance     |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|#############################|        |YAHTZEE    |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Sum        |        |        |        |#############################|
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Bonus      |        |        |        |TOTAL SCORE|        |        |
 -----------------------------          -----------------------------
```

I printed the dictionary after I changed it in order to check if it has indeed been changed.

Comment: f-strings do not automatically update. They are computed at the time of initialisation. In general, strings are immutable in Python, so they can't be updated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're expecting the f strings to update when the `points` dictionary changes, but f strings are created immutably when interpreted. Look at this example:

```py
>>> x = 10
>>> x_string = f"x is {x}"
>>> x_string
'x is 10'

>>> x = 20        # Change the value of x.
>>> x_string
'x is 10'
```

So one way to fix your problem is to define `avaliable_grid` within `print_table()`.

```py
def print_table(points):
    available_grid = [ #...
                       #...
        ]
    for i in available_grid:
        print(i)
```

I also recommend passing in `points` so that you don't get mixed up with global variables.

By the way, since you only use the `available_grid` as a way to track the string, you can get the same result with a block string.

```py
available_grid = f"""
 _____________________________          _____________________________
|           |Player 1|Player 2|        |           |Player 1|Player 2|
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Ones       |{points[str(1)]}|        |        |3 of a Kind|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Twos       |{points[str(2)]}|        |        |4 of a Kind|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Threes     |{points[str(3)]}|        |        |Full House |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Fours      |{points[str(4)]}|        |        |S. Straight|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Fives      |{points[str(5)]}|        |        |L. Straight|        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Sixes      |{points[str(6)]}|        |        |Chance     |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|#############################|        |YAHTZEE    |        |        |
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Sum        |        |        |        |#############################|
|-----------|--------|--------|        |-----------|--------|--------|
|Bonus      |        |        |        |TOTAL SCORE|        |        |
 -----------------------------          -----------------------------
"""
```

Comment: I see. is there some way where I could update the slot that you know of?